# Laravel Inertia using InertiaProgress with Axios returns: Cannot read property 'defaultPrevented' of undefined

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I am using current versions of `Laravel` & `Inertia.js`. I am also using `IntertiaProgress` and looking to use it during a file upload using `axios`

The files all upload OK but the console shows:

```
app.js:33316 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultPrevented' of undefined
```

Tracing this back it points to here in the source of `InertiaProgress`:

```
 start(event) {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      if (event.defaultPrevented) {
        return
      }

      this.inProgress++
      clearTimeout(this.timeout)
      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        Nprogress.set(0)
        Nprogress.start()
      }, this.delay)
    })
  },
```

If I `console.log(event)` I get `undefined`

My `upload()` method:

```
upload(files) {
    let url = this.$route('library.upload');
    this.$root.showLoading = true;

    const uploadConfig = {
        timeout: 10000,
        onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
            let percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
            InertiaProgress.progress(percentCompleted)
        }
    }

    InertiaProgress.start()

    axios.post(url, {
        files,
    },
        uploadConfig
    ).then(res => {
        let files = res.data.files
        if (files.length) {
            this.filesList = cloneDeep(files)
        }

        this.newFiles = []

        InertiaProgress.finish()
        this.$root.showLoading = false
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)

        InertiaProgress.finish()
        this.$root.showLoading = false
    })
},
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use NProgress directly.

Instead of:

`InertiaProgress.progress(percentCompleted)`

Like this:

`NProgress.progress(percentCompleted)`

See also: https://inertiajs.com/progress-indicators